# Azure API (facial recognition) in Flutter

Tags: azure, api, flutter, dart, mobile

I am a beginner in the development of mobile applications and I am currently using Flutter. My question is: how do I get my app to communicate with the Azure API (Microsoft) with Flutter (Dart language), so that I can do a facial recognition for authentication his access. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there's no official SDK for Dart, you'll need to call the Azure REST API's directly. Here's the documentation for the version 3.1:

https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-1-ga/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499f21b